# site is signed with a certificate that’s trusted by iOS

Tags: ios

my company wants to set up an in-house app store, and would like to distribute our iPad app wirelessly from our internal website. 
I was looking over the iOS Deployment Technical Reference Guide, and in the "Installing In-House Apps Wirelessly" section it says:

Also ensure that your .ipa file is accessible over HTTPS and that your **site is signed with a certificate that’s trusted by iOS**. Installation will fail if a self-signed certificate doesn’t have a trusted anchor and can’t be validated by the iOS device.

My question is what certificate is acceptable and trusted for this? I was looking at Verisign and Entrust, and was unsure of exactly what I was looking for. They offer "SSL Certificates", "Signing Certificates", and "User Certificates". I assume what I am looking for is an "SSL Certificate", but within this category are a variety of SSL certificates. Will any of these do or am I in the wrong place?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you have at least some understanding of how SSL certificates work. If not, be sure to read up on that a bit. http://support.apple.com/kb/PH10967 has a decent explanation that holds true for both iOS and OSX.

For the certificate to be trusted by iOS, it needs to backed by a trusted Certificate Authority. The default CAs trusted by iOS 7 can be found at http://support.apple.com/kb/ht5012. Alternately, you can also install custom certificate authorities to use a la http://nat.guyton.net/2012/01/20/adding-trusted-root-certificate-authorities-to-ios-ipad-iphone/ Once you have a certificate that was created using a trusted Certificate Authority you should be able to just use that as the server certificate (this is required for HTTPS) and go with it.